# Generic Classes in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following template classes and interface

```
public class UseCaseResponse<T> where T : class 
{
  //......
}

public interface IPresenter<T> where T : UseCaseResponse<T>, new()
{
    void Handle(T response);
}
public class JsonPresenter<T> : IPresenter<T> where T : UseCaseResponse<T>, new()
{

    public void Handle(T response)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now my question is how do I create object of different **JSonPresenter**s
Like I can do this,

```
ServiceCollection s = new ServiceCollection();
s.AddScoped<UseCaseResponse<Person>, UseCaseResponse<Person>>();
var provider = s.BuildServiceProvider();
var p = (UseCaseResponse<Person>)p.GetService(typeof(UseCaseResponse<Person>));
```

And that works, but how do I get `JsonPresenter<UseCaseResponse<Person>>` object?

Comment: What's the `ServiceCollection` code? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: its the aspnet core default DI container.

Answer (score 0):

For generics you just need to specify the concrete type arguments when creating an instance of the type. For your desired `JsonPresenter<UseCaseResponse<Person>>` it woulde be:

```
var presenter = new JsonPresenter<UseCaseResponse<Person>>();
```

Now you can do:

```
//p is the UseCaseResponse instance from your second code sample
presenter.Handle(p);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. "No implicit reference conversion"

Comment: OP uses "Curiously recursive template pattern" - so class needs to derive from generics of that class like `Person:UseCaseResponse<Person>` (for `UseCaseResponse<Person>` to work). I don't think there is a way to make `JsonPresenter<UseCaseResponse<Person>>` compile (at least nothing reasonably sane)

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that, sorry

Comment: Upon further inspection - where does the curiously recursive pattern apply here? I don't think any of the classes requires a type parameter to derive from itself, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh, I see it now :-D Time to review generics again :-D

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov wow i didn't know about that kind of pattern. is it even legal!! thanks!

Comment: @ishahrier yes it is legal (and used surprisingly often with equality: `Foo:IEquatable<Foo>`), it used more commonly with interfaces then classes as you have now. I should have noted that `where T : UseCaseResponse<T>` forces curiously recursive pattern on T to avoid confusion (as it is not immediately obvious from the example)